# Unexpected difference in experimental and theoretical results in verifying Stefan's Law

Tags: experimental-physics, thermal-radiation

This is an experiment as part of my Experimental Physics Course in college; it involves the verification of Stefan's Law. 
The experiment is pretty simple. We essentially treat an incandescent bulb as a black body, connecting it to an ammeter in series, voltmeter in parallel and a DC source in series. The idea is to increase voltage in steps of $1V$ upto $10V$ and note down the corresponding current to calculate the resistance at that temperature. By employing the relation $R_{T^\text{o} C}= R_{0^\text{o}C}(1+\alpha T),\alpha=$Temperature coefficient of resistance$=0.0045^\text{o}C$, we calculate the temperature.Then we plot a graph between the logarithm of power, given by $VI$ versus $logT$, whose slope, as dictated by Stefan's Law, is supposed to be $4$. And I would also like to think that the readings are accurate to the best of my knowledge, as it was given by our professor, and we were only required to analyse it.
So the issue is that the calculated value of slope from the data is $2.7$, which is significantly different from $4$. This was obtained by calculating the slope of the best fit line, which I also believe to be correct since the entire class obtained the same result. However, I wonder what exactly is the reason behind this stark difference.
I have a couple of thoughts in mind:
$1.$ The bulb's filament is not a perfectly black body, and even $R_{T^\text{o} C}= R_{0^\text{o}C}(1+\alpha T)$ is an approximate relation . But this again, I don't think, should cause such a drastic difference.
2. Not all the heat emitted goes into increasing the resistance. This is definitely true, since part of it is radiated away(obviously, that's exactly what we are studying). But in that case, the measured temperature should be less than the actual temperature, since $R_T$ would be smaller due to lesser heat involved. And that means the power of $T$ in Stefan's Law, as measured, should be greater.
Unfortunately I can't think of any other reason why it should go wrong. Any guesses why this might be happening?
I also have another tiny question to go with this one- in the experiment we were asked not to take the voltage beyond $10V$. What could the reason be?

Comment: What is the uncertainty of your experiment data? For, example, if your slope is $2.7\pm 0.8$, the theoretical value $4$, within two times of the uncertainty from $2.7$, agrees with your experiment value to a certain degree.

Comment: Also, a major problem you have to consider is that not all energy you put into the bulb transformed into radiation. Some must be lost from conduction and convection in air.

Comment: Some filaments are designed so the radiation is absorbed by the filament, this helps with the efficiency of the bulb.  So if the filament is a straight wire or a coil the self heating will be different as well as the length of the wires between the terminals.

Comment: At more than 10V perhaps you'll blow out the filament.